# Windows Azure | trail program

Tags: azure

I subscribed to free 90 days azure trail offered by MS. I was excited and talked about it everywhere(including my blog http://techibee.com/windows-2012/free-try-windows-server-2012-in-azure-for-90-days/1876) about the free service offered by MS and how to make use of it. Well, my excitement lasted only for 7-8 days. Today I got a message from Azure team that my subscription disabled as my computer hours exceed the monthly limit.

I am just wondering how these compute hours are calculated in my case. I configured 2 VMs(2 medium) and using them to explore stuff. I never shutdown them since creation. Anyone has idea how these two VMs constituted to limits.

Another question I have is, since the subscription is disabled for this month, I am considering purchasing few more compute hours(pay-as-you-go). If I do that now, should I shutdown the VMs when I am not using them actively? will it stop the compute hours from increasing or they will continue to charge me for even shutdown hours. All I want is, I should get billed only when I am actively using it, when I am not connected to that host, I shouldn't. Looks like this is not happened in the trail program and their calculations seems different. Can anyone here given me some clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#header-3

> Compute hours are charged whenever the Virtual Machine is deployed,
>   irrespective of whether it is running or not.

That's where all your hours went. You need to delete your VMs to prevent them using compute time.

Answer (score 0):

With the free trial account you can configure only 1 VMs medium. Probably your offered expired early becouse you configured two.

Be aware that if you create a VM and you turn it off you will be charged the same as indicated when your turn off a VM.